# Copying Attachments from parent object to child object when field changes

Tags: salesforce, apex, sfdc

Trying copying Attachments from parent object to child object when attachment gets inserted on Opportunity(Parent Obj)

I have tried writing some code.

```
trigger CopyAttachmentsToRU on Attachment (after insert) {


    Set<Id> OppIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {

        // only collect those that are for the Opportunity object (others can be ignored)
        if(file.ParentId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.getSObjectType()) {
            OppIds.add(file.ParentId);
            system.debug(OppIds);
        }
    }


    if(!OppIds.isEmpty()) {
        Map<Id,EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c> ruMap = new Map<Id,EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c>([select EIP_Opportunity__c from EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c where EIP_Opportunity__c in : OppIds]);        
        List<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();
        system.debug(ruMap);
        for(Attachment file : Trigger.new) {
            Attachment newFile = file.clone();
            newFile.ParentId = ruMap.get(file.ParentId).Id;
            attachments.add(newFile);
        }
        // finally, insert the cloned attachments
        insert attachments;   

    }

}
```

Every time an attachment gets attach to Opportunity..its not working for me !

Comment: Are you sure your org is actually using Attachments rather than the newer Files infrastructure?

Answer (score 1):

Your `ruMap` has keys made out of `EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c` ids. But you try to call `get()` on it using Opportunity Ids. This will never work. I'm surprised it doesn't throw you a null-related error, do you have some try-catch in there that just swallows the exception?

You probably need something like

```
Map<Id,EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c> ruMap = new Map<Id,EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c>();
for(EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c obj : [select Id, EIP_Opportunity__c from EIP_Lead_Rental_Object__c where EIP_Opportunity__c in : OppIds]){
    ruMap.put(obj.EIP_Opportunity__c, obj);
}
```

and then you can

```
for(Attachment file : Trigger.new){
    if(ruMap.containsKey(file.ParentId)){
        Attachment newFile = file.clone();
        newFile.ParentId = ruMap.get(file.ParentId).Id;
        attachments.add(newFile);
    }
}
```